# Error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi código, cuando intento compilar me marca el siguiente error:

> error: cannot find symbol method
>   setLatestEventInfo(NotifyService,CharSequence,CharSequence,PendingIntent)

este es mi código:

```
    public class NotifyService extends Service {

    /**
     * Class for clients to access
     */
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        NotifyService getService() {
            return NotifyService.this;
        }
    }

    // Unique id to identify the notification.
    private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
    // Name of an intent extra we can use to identify if this service was started to create a notification
    public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "otrointento.prueba.INTENT_NOTIFY";
    // The system notification manager
    private NotificationManager mNM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
            showNotification();

        // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    /**
     * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
     */
    private void showNotification() {
        // This is the 'title' of the notification
        CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";
        // This is the icon to use on the notification
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        // This is the scrolling text of the notification
        CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us.";
        // What time to show on the notification
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();


        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);

        // Clear the notification when it is pressed
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Send the notification to the system.
        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

        // Stop the service when we are finished
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Alguien me puede ayudar? Se lo agradecería!

EDITO: @Elenasys

LOG:

```
01-05 01:28:56.622 19968-19968/otrointento.prueba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: otrointento.prueba, PID: 19968
                                                                 Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, iconPack:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, fontPkg:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.saalim.cm.theme.dusk}
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4458)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void otrointento.prueba.ScheduleService.setAlarm(java.util.Calendar)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at otrointento.prueba.ScheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(ScheduleClient.java:64)
                                                                     at otrointento.prueba.MainActivity_noti.onDateSelectedButtonClick(MainActivity_noti.java:58)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

codigo nuevo:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    /**
     * Class for clients to access
     */
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        NotifyService getService() {
            return NotifyService.this;
        }
    }

    // Unique id to identify the notification.
    private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
    // Name of an intent extra we can use to identify if this service was started to create a notification
    public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "otrointento.prueba.INTENT_NOTIFY";
    // The system notification manager
    private NotificationManager mNM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
            showNotification();

        // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    /**
     * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
     */
    private void showNotification() {
        // This is the 'title' of the notification
        CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";
        // This is the icon to use on the notification
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        // This is the scrolling text of the notification
        CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us.";
        // What time to show on the notification
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("Titulo")
                .setContentText("Resumen.")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notManager.notify(123456, builder.build());

        // Stop the service when we are finished
    }
}
```

EDITO2: @Elenasys

MainActivity_noti.java

```
public class MainActivity_noti extends Activity  {
    // This is a handle so that we can call methods on our service
    private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;
    // This is the date picker used to select the date for our notification
    private DatePicker picker;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_noti);

        // Create a new service client and bind our activity to this service
        scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(this);
        scheduleClient.doBindService();

        // Get a reference to our date picker
        picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.scheduleTimePicker);
    }

    /**
     * This is the onClick called from the XML to set a new notification
     */
    public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v){
        // Get the date from our datepicker
        int day = picker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = picker.getMonth();
        int year = picker.getYear();
        // Create a new calendar set to the date chosen
        // we set the time to midnight (i.e. the first minute of that day)
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date, this activity talks to the client that talks to the service
        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);
        // Notify the user what they just did
        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for: "+ day +"/"+ (month+1) +"/"+ year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // When our activity is stopped ensure we also stop the connection to the service
        // this stops us leaking our activity into the system *bad*
        if(scheduleClient != null)
            scheduleClient.doUnbindService();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

NotifyService.java

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    /**
     * Class for clients to access
     */
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        NotifyService getService() {
            return NotifyService.this;
        }
    }

    // Unique id to identify the notification.
    private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
    // Name of an intent extra we can use to identify if this service was started to create a notification
    public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "vrteam.birthday.INTENT_NOTIFY";
    // The system notification manager
    private NotificationManager mNM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
            showNotification();

        // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    /**
     * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
     */
    private void showNotification() {

        NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) getApplication()
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("Titulo")
                .setContentText("Resumen.")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifyService.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notManager.notify(123456, builder.build());
    }
}
```

ScheduleClient.java

```
public class ScheduleClient {

    // The hook into our service
    private vrteam.birthday.ScheduleService mBoundService;
    // The context to start the service in
    private Context mContext;
    // A flag if we are connected to the service or not
    private boolean mIsBound;

    public ScheduleClient(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Call this to connect your activity to your service
     */
    public void doBindService() {
        // Establish a connection with our service
        mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, ScheduleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    /**
     * When you attempt to connect to the service, this connection will be called with the result.
     * If we have successfully connected we instantiate our service object so that we can call methods on it.
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with our service has been established,
            // giving us the service object we can use to interact with our service.
            mBoundService = ((ScheduleService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mBoundService = null;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Tell our service to set an alarm for the given date
     * @param c a date to set the notification for
     */
    public void setAlarmForNotification(Calendar c){
        mBoundService.setAlarm(c);
    }

    /**
     * When you have finished with the service call this method to stop it
     * releasing your connection and resources
     */
    public void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            mContext.unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

ScheduleService.java:

```
public class ScheduleService extends Service {

    /**
     * Class for clients to access
     */
    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        ScheduleService getService() {
            return ScheduleService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("ScheduleService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients. See
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    /**
     * Show an alarm for a certain date when the alarm is called it will pop up a notification
     */
    public void setAlarm(Calendar c) {
        // This starts a new thread to set the alarm
        // You want to push off your tasks onto a new thread to free up the UI to carry on responding
        new AlarmTask(this, c).run();
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

}
```

activity_main_noti.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/scheduleTimePicker"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onDateSelectedButtonClick"
        android:text="Set notification for this date" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PRUEBA" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente estas usando un targetSDK 23 o mayor, ya que el método  [setLatestEventInfo()](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html) fue removido en el API 23.

Puedes bajar el `targetSdkVersion` a una versión menor a 23 o usar la clase [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html), este es un ejemplo:

```
   NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle("Titulo")
            .setContentText("Resumen.")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);     
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);   
    notManager.notify(123456, builder.build());
```

Agrego unos tutoriales en español:

**[Notificaciones expandibles y normales](http://www.franciscomlopez.com/android-notification-styles/)**

[**Notificaciones en Android**](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/notificaciones-en-android-ii-barra-de-estado/)

Comment: Y cuál debo usar ahora? @Elenasys

Comment: Listo, usa NotificationCompat de hecho agregué tutoriales

Comment: muchas gracias @Elenasys ! me da error de variable ctx me podrías ayudar?

Comment: Es el contexto estas en una Activity? Puedes usar getApplicationContext().

Comment: He editado el primer mensaje con el LOG y el codigo nuevo, ojalá me puedas ayudar, gracias por toda tu ayuda! @Elenasys

Comment: Me podrías ayudar por favor, no sé como implementar lo que me comentas a mi código, siempre tengo errores como los que te puse en el primer comentario @Elenasys

Comment: Este error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick es de la forma en que ejecutas el metodo Click, como lo estas llamando? definido en el layout o con un Clicklistener?

Comment: He dejado el código que estoy utilizando, completo, para esta acción con lo que me comentas en tu solución añadido (NotifyService), ojalá me puedas ayudar, gracias @Elenasys

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51242/discussion-between-elenasys-and-usernameyo).